listView and CustomAdapter (Android)
enter image description here
i am trying  to build my listview using customadapter the listview should show three items on the screem unless it shows two items good but the third one does not appear with full data .
creating listview using custom adapter (Android).....


Did you check data what you get back from backend in "Log"? Like below   Log.d("mytag", "Here my data is------- " + data.size);


i am filling my arrayList with data manually and my arrayList consists of 3 indexes .but just like you see the listview only shows the first two indexes.
